# Change paint on animated Path (android)

Tags: android, path

I have a Path and an object that is following the path implemented. How to make that the moving object paints another color on the path that it has passed.

here the link to the image(maybe it explains better what I mean):[moving object on path](http://postimage.org/image/4anj8g3r1/)

thx for your help :)

Comment: Where is your code? What is not working? etc.

Comment: if you need the code for simple path and paint declaration and initialization to answer the question then you...
I just needed a hint like "you should look at DashPathEffect".I am sure you will do it better next time :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how it can be done :)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new SampleView(this));
    }

    private static class SampleView extends View {
        private Paint mPaint,followingPaint;
        private Path mPath=new Path();
        private PathEffect mEffect;
        private float mPhase;
        private PathMeasure pm;
        private float pmLen; 

        public SampleView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

            mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            followingPaint= new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            followingPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            followingPaint.setStrokeWidth(8);

            mPath.moveTo(50, 150);
            mPath.quadTo(100,200,150, 150);
            mPath.quadTo(200,100,300, 150);
            pm=new PathMeasure(mPath,false);
            pmLen = pm.getLength();

        }

        @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

            mEffect = new DashPathEffect(new float[] {pmLen, pmLen}, mPhase+pmLen);
                mPhase -= 4;
            invalidate();     
            followingPaint.setPathEffect(mEffect);
            mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            followingPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, followingPaint);
        }
    }
}
```